# Is it true that the following definition of a convex function cannot be used in a more general way?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

One definition for convex functions I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) was that 'the line segment between *any* two points on the graph of the function always lies above or on the graph'. That makes sense. However, am I right in suggesting that this is not a suitable definition for convexity on a particular interval? To explain why I think this, consider the graph $y=x^3$ on the interval $[-0.5,1]$:

[image]

This function is clearly not convex on the interval $[-0.5,1]$. However, using the definition above, it does meet the criterion that the line segment between those two points always lies above or on the graph. What the above definition really tells us is that $y=x^3$ is not a convex function. It doesn't say whether the function is convex or concave over a particular interval, and cannot be used as such. Otherwise, we get contradictions such as '$y=x^3$ is convex over the interval $[-0.5,1]$', when it clearly is not.

So this definition helps us show that a function is convex everywhere, or not convex everywhere. It tells us whether a function is a convex function or not a convex function. What it can't tell us is whether a function is convex for every point in an interval. (To show this, we might use the second derivative test, for example.) Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct $f(x) = x^3$ is not convex on the interval $[-0.5, 1]$ (I assume you made a typo when you wrote $[0.5,1])$. However, this agrees with the Wikipedia definition: try the points $(-0.5, (-0.5)^3)$ and $(-0.4, (-0.4)^3)$. Is the line segment passing through these points still above the graph? (It's not!) So in fact the Wikipedia definition *does* tell you if a real valued function defined on an interval is convex. Remember, the definition states "for *any* two points on the graph."

Comment: Thanks for correcting my typo. This is a very nice answer. I was wondering if you check that I understand correctly: When we are trying to demonstrate that a function is convex, we are looking at the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$, and if we find a concave interval, then we know the function is not a convex function. Similarly, if we look at the interval $[a,b]$ of a function, and find a concave interval *within* $[a,b]$, then we know it's not convex on $[a,b]$. It might be convex in places, but it needs to be convex everywhere on the interval to meet our definition.

Comment: Oh, and I did check the $[-0.5,-0.4]$ interval. It's concave there, meaning we conclude $y=x^3$ is not convex on the interval $[-0.5,1]$.

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct. Some underlying assumptions that I want to point out is that your function is real valued, i.e. functions with codomain $\mathbb{R}$. And the domain in the cases you presented are $\mathbb{R}$ and $[a,b]$, respectively. Convexity can actually be made more general, and another side note is that there are functions (or parts of functions) which are neither concave nor convex (e.g. a constant function).

Comment: Thank you once again! Unfortunately I haven't met complex numbers properly yet, but it will be good to keep this in mind, particularly if I start a University course in mathematics. I'm very happy to understand concepts such as these a bit more rigorously, as school isn't the best place for mathematical rigour.